# Java: Loading SSL Keystore via a resource

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore

If I have:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", '/etc/certificates/fdms/WS1001237590._.1.ks');
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", 'DV8u4xRVDq');
System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");
```

I'm able to open a secure connection without a problem.

However, I'd like to have the certificates stored directly in the war, so I use: (The file input stream will eventually become a resource stream, but I'm doing this to get it to work.)

```
System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
ks.load(new FileInputStream("/etc/certificates/fdms/WS1001237590._.1.ks"), "DV8u4xRVDq".toCharArray());
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
kmf.init(ks, "DV8u4xRVDq".toCharArray());
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
```

Now, if I open the same connection, I get: `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure`

Comment: What are you then doing with the `SSLContext` instance `sc`? Are you using it to create a `SocketFactory` and setting that into the object making the connections?

Comment: I'm not doing anything with it. I'm using Axis to then connect to the web service.

Comment: Remember to close the FileInputStream, sample code in the javadoc of KeyStore explicitly closes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For posterity's sake, all of this was far too complicated, and we pretty much just had a check in the static block:

```
if( environment == 'production') {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",                    '/etc/certificates/prod/keystore.ks');
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword",            'password');
    System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");
} else {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",                    '/etc/certificates/test/keystore.ks');
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword",            'password');
    System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");
}
```

Comment: I'm facing a similar issues and after setting the system properties I get : Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:323) at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:217)

Any ideas ?

Comment: "if( environment == 'production') {... System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true"); " - I *really* hope that is a typo :-/.

Answer (score 11):

I had to do something similar a while back. I had a certificate file and I had to figure out a way to load it in and use it for an SSL connection. Hopefully what I did will help you out.

First I had to create a trust manager:

```
public class MyX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

    X509TrustManager pkixTrustManager;

    MyX509TrustManager() throws Exception {

        String certFile = "/certificates/MyCertFile.cer";

        Certificate myCert = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509").generateCertificate(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(valicertFile));

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keyStore.load(null, "".toCharArray());
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("myCert", myCert);

        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX");
        trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);

        TrustManager trustManagers[] = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

        for(TrustManager trustManager : trustManagers) {
            if(trustManager instanceof X509TrustManager) {
                pkixTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManager;
                return;
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("Couldn't initialize");
    }

    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        pkixTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        pkixTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
    }

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return pkixTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
    }
}
```

After that I had to create a socket factory that used my trust manager:

```
public class MySSLProtocolSocketFactory implements SecureProtocolSocketFactory {

    private SSLContext sslContext = null;

    public MySSLProtocolSocketFactory() {
        super();
    }

    private static SSLContext createMySSLContext() {
        try {
            MyX509TrustManager myX509TrustManager = new MyX509TrustManager();
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, new MyX509TrustManager[] { myX509TrustManager}, null);
            return context;
        }

        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.error(Log.Context.Net, e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private SSLContext getSSLContext() {
        if(this.sslContext == null) {
            this.sslContext = createMySSLContext();
        }

        return this.sslContext;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress clientHost, int clientPort) throws IOException {
        return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket(host, port, clientHost, clientPort);
    }

    public Socket createSocket(final String host, final int port, final InetAddress localAddress, final int localPort, final HttpConnectionParams params) throws IOException {
        if(params == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameters may not be null");
        }

        int timeout = params.getConnectionTimeout();
        SocketFactory socketFactory = getSSLContext().getSocketFactory();

        if(timeout == 0) {
            return socketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localAddress, localPort);
        }

        else {
            Socket socket = socketFactory.createSocket();
            SocketAddress localAddr = new InetSocketAddress(localAddress, localPort);
            SocketAddress remoteAddr = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
            socket.bind(localAddr);
            socket.connect(remoteAddr, timeout);
            return socket;
        }
    }

    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException {
        return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket(host, port);
    }

    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return ((obj != null) && obj.getClass().equals(MySSLProtocolSocketFactory.class));
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return MySSLProtocolSocketFactory.class.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Then I used that socket factory to send my POST:

```
Protocol.registerProtocol("myhttps", new Protocol("myhttps", new MySSLProtocolSocketFactory(), 443));

PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod("myhttps://some.url.here");

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
int status = client.executeMethod(postMethod);
```

The only thing I couldn't figure out was how to simply add the certificate file to the regular keystore. All the example source code I found during my research pointed to creating a socket factor and then registering a protocol with that socket factory. Perhaps there is a way to simply use the socket factory to make a connection without registering a protocol; I haven't investigated that thoroughly. In my particular situation, creating a specific protocol was necessary. Hopefully this will get your further along the way. I admit it seems a bit roundabout; I felt the same way when I did it initially. But this was the only way I got it to work. Maybe other people have a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

With Axis, I think you need to configure its `SSLSocketFactory` via:

```
AxisProperties.setProperty("axis.socketSecureFactory",
    "com.example.MySSLSocketFactory");
```

where `com.example.MySSLSocketFactory` is your class that implements `org.apache.axis.components.net.SecureSocketFactory` (you could extend `org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory` perhaps).

In the `create` method, create a socket using the socket factory obtained from the `SSLContext` you've configured.

Comment: The one line of code you gave solves the problem and then it's up to the developer to implement a custom SecureSocketFactory.

Answer (score 2):

If you want, here's an API to create SSLSocket and SSLServerSocket easily:

https://github.com/gpotter2/SSLKeystoreFactories

It does not require any other jars.... just get the files and use them like:

```
SSLSocket s = SSLSocketKeystoreFactory.getSocketWithCert(ip, port, 
   Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/mykey.jks"), "password")
```

Or:

```
SSLServerSocket s = SSLServerSocketKeystoreFactory.getSocketWithCert(port, 
   Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/mykey.jks"), "password")
```

That's much easier to use :)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, I solved creating a function that returns an SSL context using a keystore coming from and input stream.

```
   protected SSLContext getSslCtx(InputStream is, String password) {
    try {
        // Load keystore
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keystore.load(is, password.toCharArray());

        // Load trust manager
        TrustManagerFactory trustMgrFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustMgrFactory.init(keystore);

        // Load key manager
        KeyManagerFactory keyMgrFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyMgrFactory.init(keystore, password.toCharArray());

        // Create SSL context
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        ctx.init(keyMgrFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustMgrFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
        return ctx;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Hope this helps.