# Need Apache Axis (not Axis2) client example for calling web service with SSL

Tags: ssl, self-signed, webservices-client, axis

I have searched in vain for a straightforward example of calling a web service requiring SSL authentication and that has a self-signed certificate. I already have the code to be able to trust all certs, so you don't need to provide that.  Just a simple example of being able to provide to the service the authentication parameters - username, password, and any other authentication-related parameters, transports, and headers necessary to authenticate successfully and make use of the service.  Right now I am using Axis 1.4.  Your responses will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256676/372643

You'll need to initialise your socket factory from an `SSLContext` that trusts this particular self-signed certificate.

Alternatively, you could import this specific certificate in your trust store (`cacerts` in your JRE directory), or import it into a copy of this file and use it as a global trust store by pointing the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` system property to it (the default password is `changeit`).