# Truststore in JavaFX jar

Tags: javafx, truststore

I have a JavaFX application that has a GUI that uses the Confluence API to create pages, delete pages and so on. For that to work I had to get a SSL certificate of Confluence with the browser, create a truststore and implement the certificate in the truststore. There is only this certificate in there and everyone can get this certificate with their own browser. So in my understanding this truststore is not really something "secret". But my problem is: How do I implement the truststore in my code so that other users can use this application when it will be an executable jar?

When only I am using this locally, I used this in the initialize-method:

```java
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "path\to\truststore.jks");
```

But of course, when I create an executable jar file, other users do not have this file on their machine. So my approach here was to put the truststore.jks in src/main/resources and do this in the initialize-method:

```java
try (InputStream truststoreStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/truststore.jks")) {
         System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "path\to\truststore.jks");

         KeyStore truststoreKeystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
         truststoreKeystore.load(truststoreStream, truststorePassword.toCharArray());
      } catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

But I think to implement the truststore directly in the project is not the right way.

So I do not know how to fix the problem so that other users on different machines can use this application.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is an executable jar the right way to go?  You could instead package using `jlink` or `jpackage`, including the truststore file with the distributed package and loaded from the startup script.

Comment: "*I think to implement the truststore directly in the project is not the right way.*" -> why? what do you think is wrong with such an approach? The main issue I can think of is that certificates in the trust store have an expiry date, so they need to be updated (eventually).  You could require the users to update your application to get updated trusted certificates, or you could allow them to modify a file to include the certificates for you to pick up.  What to do depends on your requirements and design.

Comment: While you can [set your own truststore in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247746/java-loading-ssl-keystore-via-a-resource), it is complex to do so in comparison to configuring it via properties that load the truststore from a file (at least as far as I know).  The link I provided also configures a keystore for mutual auth, which you don't need, but even without that, it is not straight-forward.  Also, the code you have which is attempting to load the truststore from a resource in your question appears incorrect to me.

Comment: I never heard of jlink or jpackage. I need to look into these. Thank you.

Comment: "truststore directly in the project" --> With my approach where I load in the truststore, I have the password for the truststore directly in my code. This seems "unsecure", but I really do not have the experience to say if this is important, because I think my truststore does not represent something secure. And you mentioned that my code seems to be incorrect - that could absolutely be the case. I did not had the chance to test this on another machine. Could you explain what is incorrect?

Comment: If you use `jpackage` then you can include the trust store in the application image via the `--input` option and set the system property via the `--java-options` option. The value of the system property would be `$APPDIR/<relative-path>` (where `<relative-path>` is the path to the trust store relative to the directory you pass to `--input`).

Comment: *"Could you explain what is incorrect?"* -> It is calling `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "path\to\truststore.jks");`, so that will load the truststore from a file (not a resource) and the rest of the code seems to be then irrelevant, it seems to load a trust store, but I don't know what you do with it (e.g. you don't have code that configures an SSL socket to use it like the prior example I linked).  I can't realistically answer your question better than the linked answer (assuming that I understood your question and the linked answer answers it).

Comment: Regarding a password to protect the truststore, that doesn't matter.  The truststore contains certificates not private keys.  Certificates are just wrappers for public keys with additional context info, they are designed to be public information, not private information.

Comment: I advise you to consider following Slaw's advice and use jpackage (or some other mechanism) which packages the truststore as a file beside your application.  For example, you can use a maven assembly to zip up your app and required files or use the maven-javafx-plugin jlink target to create an application zip and have a shell script to launch the app that applies the required system properties to locate the truststore file.

Comment: All right, thank you both. I will look into your suggestions.